# Prove that if $n\geq 4$ is even then $2^n -1$ is not prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Since $n\geq 4$ is even, we can let $n=2k$. Then $2k\geq 4$ or $k\geq 2$ which can be substituted where we have $2^{2k}-1 = (2^k)^2 - 1^2 = (2^k+1)(2^k-1)$. Since $k \geq 2$, we have that $2^k\geq 4$.

This is where things get derailed. Where do I go from here?

Comment: you are (almost) done already

Comment: $\gcd(2^k+1,2^k-1)=\gcd(2^k+1,2)=1$

Answer (score 6):

If $k>1$ then
$$
4^k-1=\underbrace{(2^k+1)}_{>1}\underbrace{(2^k-1)}_{>1}.
$$
If $k=1$ then $4^k-1$ is prime.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to write a number as product of two numbers none of them equals to $\pm 1$.

This says it is not a prime.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different approach, if $n=2m\ge4$, then $2^n-1\gt3$, but $2^{2m}-1\equiv(-1)^{2m}-1\equiv0$ mod $3$, so $3\mid2^n-1$.